# (Raspberry Pi)Exagear: Installing wget on Guest System

Tags: raspberry-pi, wget, invoke, udev, dpkg

I'm trying to install wget on my Raspberry Pi running Debian 8 on Exagear Desktop as a Guest System. When I try to install wget, it just gives me this as an Output:

```
root@RaspiServer:~# sudo apt-get install wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libicu52 libpsl0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libicu52 libpsl0 wget
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7435 kB of archives.
After this operation, 30.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u4) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
invoke-rc.d: You are trying to invoke service *udev* of the host system from the guest one.
This action is prohibited; please refer to the user guide for more details.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install new version of ExaGear Desktop 1.5. There problem with udev is fixed.

Comment: Even though I changed nothing to my previous Installation of Exagear, it now works fine. Just reinstalled it! Thanks alot!

Comment: Please, keep in mind it happens on v 1.4 and earlyes if udev package update. Some was changed in udev new version which cause this message. But usually this error might be ignored.

Comment: Ok, so apparently as soon as I run `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` the error message appears again. Does the Package: software-properties-common include the new Version of udev? If so, how can i downgrade to the old one?

Comment: The error message appears again when trying to install git

Comment: Why dont you want install new version of exagear?

Comment: So I did some sort of "Update" it was actually just a new Wine version but it seems to work now. If I get some new Errors I'll be posting them here. Thanks a lot! PS: The reason I cant use Exagear Desktop 1.5 is because its only for Raspberry Pi 2 and 3. Thats atleast what the E-Mail said.

Comment: What rpi version do you use?

Comment: I now have a Raspberry Pi 3 running the latest Raspbian and Exagear 1.5. Right now I have the problem that whenever I try to run sudo (even with `sudo apt-get update`) it says: `bash: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: Did you use vanila raspbian or made some modification, changed kernel?

Comment: Vanilla Kernel. Its crazy because once again, the reinstallation of Raspbian did it.

Comment: On previous raspbian everything was ok but with latest rised this problem. Correct?

Comment: Ok my fault. After the reinstallation I ran 'dist-upgrade'. This propably did the job. So the Error was only on the old Raspbian Version. Everything works fine now. :)

Comment: distr-uograte in host or guest system?

Comment: In the Host-System